# Passing string variable by reference

Tags: c

I've this piece of code :

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <string.h>

void b(char *in, char ** out);

int main()
{
    char a[] = {'w','o','r','l','d','\0'};
    char *d = nullptr;
    b(a, &d);
    printf("hello %s\n", d);
    return 0;
}

void b(char *in, char ** out)
{
    char tmp[10];
    for(int i=0;i<6;i++)
        tmp[i]=in[i];

    *out=tmp;

    printf("%s\n", *out);
}
```

I except to get theses printf :

```
world
hello world
```

But I get these :

```
world
hello
```

Why the d variable isn't fullfilled ? :(

Thanks for any clue about that !

Comment: You did not allocated memory for `d`.

Comment: Filled with what? The contents of a dead local variable? Look up "dangling pointer" and consider using _actual_ [std::] string variables... ;)

Comment: @Eraklon If they had, they would have leaked it.

Comment: @Eraklon That is not a problem because they never dereference `**out`.

Comment: There is no reference in your code (no string either), what do you mean in subject?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Inside of `b()`, you are setting the `char*` referred by `out` to point at a local `char[]` array, which is NOT being null-terminated (thus breaking `"%s"` in `printf()`), but also WILL go out of scope when `b()` exits, thus the caller (ie `main()`) ends up with a dangling `char*` pointer to invalid memory.

You tagged your question as [c++](/questions/tagged/c%2b%2b). C++ is not C.  You should use `std::string` instead of `char[]` in this situation, eg:

```cpp
#include <iostream>
#include <string>

void b(const std::string &in, std::string &out);

int main()
{
    std::string a = "world";
    std::string d;
    b(a, d);
    std::cout << "hello " << d << "\n";
    return 0;
}

void b(const std::string &in, std::string &out)
{
    std::string tmp = in.substr(0, 6);
    out = tmp;
    std::cout << out << "\n";
}
```

Otherwise, if you really want to use `char*`, in C or C++, you will need to use dynamic memory allocation, eg:

```cpp
#include <stdio.h>  // or <cstdio> in C++
#include <string.h> // or <cstring> in C++

void b(char *in, char ** out);

int main()
{
    char a[] = "world";
    char *d = nullptr;
    b(a, &d);
    printf("hello %s\n", d);
    delete[] d; // or free() in C
    return 0;
}

void b(char *in, char ** out)
{
    char *tmp = new char[7]; // or malloc() in C
    for(int i = 0; i < 6; ++i) {
        tmp[i] = in[i];
    }
    tmp[6] = '\0';

    *out = tmp;

    printf("%s\n", *out);
}
```

Comment: Sorry for the bad tag, and thanks for the second solution : i understand now the mistake :)